# Preparing/Storing freshly made noodles/pasta

Tags: storage-method, noodles

We picked up a noodle maker recently - it mixes dough than extrudes noodles kinda like this

[image]

I figure I could prepare a large batch - and store it somehow.

What's a good way to store home made noodles? Precooking is fine (the 'proper' cooking time for this is *about* 6 minutes.) though I'd much rather not dust it with flour if there's any alternative to that.

Freezing would be awesome especially if we could avoid dusting it with flour.

A few days would be fine. A week's better.

Comment: Don't precook, follow instructions [here](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/50253/how-to-store-homemade-pasta-without-freezing/50256#50256) - dupe?

Comment: Possibly! But we're fine with freezing. And we don't need to dry it. And... yeah, pretty much I'm fine with everything they dosen't want to do

Comment: If you're not liberally coating it in flour, it can stick together ... unless you make sure that nothing's touching when drying.  Typically, you throw some flour on it as it's coming out of the machine, but you give it a shake to rid it of massive excesses before you hang or nest it to dry.  The flour also helps to absorb some of the moisture from the pasta, so I suspect not doing it would result in longer drying times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spread on a floured plate in one layer (usually multiple plates), place in freezer, then, when frozen, move to freezer bags. You may have to tap plate on counter (I use plastic plates) to loosen pasta that may have frozen to plate. It will last at least a month in the freezer in this state.  When ready to cook, simply put in boiling water directly from freezer.